# Particular website is not accessible when specific DNS is used

Tags: dns, website

Particular website is not accessible when specific DNS is used.We can ping to that website even if cannot browse.Also in some cases can reach the domain by using IP address (Ex: "http://xx.xx.xx.x.x").If we change to other DNS such as Google public DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4), it worked properly.what may be the issue? How to make a website accessible from all DNS servers? Is there any setting to be made ? any server side options?

Comment: Check with tools like `nslookup` or `dig` what is the actual answer from those DNS serwers for query about mentioned domain. The answers should be the same unless there was a recent change that did not propagete evenly yet. There is a possibility that one of DNS server is blocking particular sites.

Comment: How long ago did you make any DNS changes?